# Select UIImageView border and image With UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to change a UIImageView border size with UIGestureRecognizer, or the image position if the user selects the image inside the Image View. Is there a way to separate the two to select the right one depending the users touch? the touch are the same type. The image does need to be repositioned in the center of the new frame.

What i have so far is a fixed Uiimageview with the inside image that can be dragged to be cropped. What i want is to add the resizable imageView to the features.

Comment: You need to supply more information. For instance, are both of the gestures the same type, or is one a swipe and the other a tap for example? Does the image that needs to be repositioned take up the entire image view? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i updated the question thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is wrap your `UIImageView` in a `UIView` and do the actions based on which object is selected. (Your `UIImageView` should have constraints to the sides of the `UIView` so when resized it resizes properly).

Comment: yes but how do i select the right one `(UIGestureRecognizer*) sender.view`  is returning a `UIImageView` instead of a `UIImage`. is there another Api tool to get the right object.

Comment: `UIImage` is the property of `UIImageView` (as a `backgroundColor` or something) - so you can't interact with it directly. That's why you need to put your `UIImageView` inside a `UIView` and manipulate the way you want.